# Does venus have plasma in its atmosphere?

Tags: thermodynamics, atmospheric-science, planets, plasma-physics

Is it hot enough on Venus for thermal collisions to ionize molecules? If not, what temperature would it have to be?

Answer (score 2):

See e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saha_ionization_equation. Typical ionization energy for gases in planetary atmospheres are 14eV. The temperature on the surface of Venus is around 750K, which corresponds to an energy of 0.064eV. The exponential in the Saha-Langmuir equation will therefor basically completely suppress the existence of ionized atoms at that temperature.

Comment: Actually, the upper part of Venus' atmosphere is highly ionized, forming an ionosphere.  The ionization has nothing to do with temperature and everything to do with photoionization (i.e., UV, X-ray, etc.).  It is true that the majority of the atmosphere is neutral, like Earth's, but the top-most layers are ionized.  The lack of an intrinsic magnetic field also leads to several other interesting aspects.

Comment: That's correct, but I don't think it's what the OP was asking for. I have also found some interesting facts with regards to ionization due to cosmic rays. It seems that despite the density Venus has some mighty strong showers going on in the dense part of its atmosphere, so it could be quite interesting to do atmospheric and high energy physics there.

Comment: Ah yes... I saw the title and glanced at the "meat" of the OP a little too quickly.

Answer (score 0):

Well all planets have an ionosphere. Venus has it too. However it is not hot enough to have the whole atmosphere to be ionized. For this it has to have a minimal temperature of 5000 degrees Celsius.